# smtplib confustion looking to understand

Tags: python, windows, smtp, smtplib

I am just using windows powershell, python 3.4, and the smtp library. Do I need to set anything else up to solve this error?

```
        >>> s=smtplib.SMTP("localhost")
        Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
        File "Z:\Python34\lib\smtplib.py", line 242, in __init__
        (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
        File "Z:\Python34\lib\smtplib.py", line 321, in connect
        self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
        File "Z:\Python34\lib\smtplib.py", line 292, in _get_socket
           self.source_address)
        File "Z:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 509, in create_connection
             raise err
        File "Z:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 500, in create_connection
            sock.connect(sa)
          ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Comment: `smtplib.SMTP("localhost")` will try to establish a connection to `localhost`. Do you run a mailserver locally?

Comment: that i do not. i just have my laptop and my wifi connection, complements of Starbucks.